# Multisite Firebase deploy Hosting Error 500

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I try to deploy a little webpage with firebase hosting for some tests.

I don't want it to be hosted on the "main" url of the firebase project. Since it's already taken by the main website.

So I created another site like this :

[sorry, its in french, but you get the idea, and how can I add a picture without you having to click on the link ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70kr0.png)

Then I just added firebase to the project and wrote this firebase.json :

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "target": "thumbnail",
    "public": "dist/spotify-thumbnail",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then to deploy I type on the console :

```sh
firebase target:apply hosting thumbnail thumbnail-spotify.web.app
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

But I get :

```sh
=== Deploying to 'pocspotifyautomate'...

i  deploying hosting

Error: HTTP Error: 500, Internal error encountered.
```

Other stackoverflow and forum talks about bugs on Firebase platform side, but that was years ago, and maybe not the case here, since I can deploy the main website without any issue.
s
Do someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in `firebase.json` file if in line target you have this `"target": "thumbnail"`. In `.firebaserc` file you should have some thing like this:

```
{
  "targets": {
    "your-project-name": {
      "hosting": {
        "thumbnail": [ // here is your target you have to have seted up in firebase.json
          "thumbnail-spotify" // here is hosting URL prefix you have in firebase console
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "projects": {
    "default": "your-project-name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have this as .firebaserc :

```
{
"projects": {
    "default": "pocspotifyautomate"
  },
  "targets": {
    "pocspotifyautomate": {
      "hosting": {
        "thumbnail": [
          "thumbnail-test2.web.app"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats very weird, I must do something wrong, but I can't see what. 
Its just this target that bug, others work.

Comment: @MartinRabaud I edited this might help you. Please vote up and mark my answer as best one ( you can do it under votes ).